# AngularJS filter with integer comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

so I have a "price" field on my site made using JQuery-UI slider. This field consists of 2 integer values: minPrice, and maxPrice.

Assume I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
objarr=[
 {
  'name'='item1',
  'price'=100
 },
 {
  'name'='item2',
  'price'=200
 },...
]
```

and also the following div with ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objarr">
  {{obj.name}}: ${{obj.price}}
</div>
```

How do I create a filter such that only objets with obj['price'] > minPrice and obj['price'] < maxPrice will show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple helper function in controller:

```
$scope.filterRange = function(obj) {
    return obj.price > $scope.range.minPrice && obj.price <= $scope.range.maxPrice;
};
```

and use it in HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objarr | filter:filterRange">
    {{obj.name}}: ${{obj.price}}
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/uoynjdSI1ajrm02qp3v8?p=preview

Comment: When I tried this method, it didn't work because the value for $scope.range was set *after* the objects have loaded. Also the filter didn't get updated after the values for $scope.range changed.

Comment: In both cases you probably don't trigger $digest loop.

Comment: simple solution, superb :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to write an Angular filter

```
app.filter('pricebetween', function(){
  return function(items, min, max) {
      var filtered = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item, key) {
          if(item.price <= max && item.price >= min) { 
              filtered.push(item);
          }
      });
      return filtered;
  };
});
```

And then in the code

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in list | pricebetween:300:500">
```

In plnkr example I also have greater than filter.

http://plnkr.co/edit/f0hJpwK4TrwdgJvPRZRo

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-show filter :) , it is very easy and fits in your question , use it like that , 
 span> {{obj.name}}: ${{obj.price}} span>
 docs for ng-show: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Best Wishes :)

Comment: it is so , but in case of large number of datas in use.